# Keyboard key works randomly

Tags: keyboard

I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 few weeks ago. Since, I've keyboard issues.

I've an AZERTY keyboard but configured in QWERTY. 
My "m" and "delete" keys work randomly. I removed and clean them. There is no effect.

I tried 
`showkey --scancodes`. No answers when I type on these two keys.

For the moment, it's working but tomorrow it might be not working.

How can I be sure it's not a software problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: Nope. I figure out that after 1 hour running, keys work. May be there is a contact failure and the heat fix it. So, I've my answer, it's an hardware issue. Thanks.